# Function is not working with varchar records

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-function

I have a function that in theory will give the country name as output when the input is the city name:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.country_by_city(city varchar, OUT Country varchar)  
RETURNS varchar  
LANGUAGE SQL AS 
$function$   
    SELECT c.country     
    FROM country c   
    JOIN city c2 ON c2.country_id = c.country_id     
    WHERE c2.city = $1   
$function$ 
;
```

And it's working if I will change c2.city to c2.city_id but when I am trying to call a function with a `varchar` column in it, for example :

```
SELECT public.country_by_city(Abha);
```

I get this error:

> SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "abha" does not exist

I tried to use `UPPER()` or `INITCAP()`, and it didn't help. It's worth mentioning that city name records in the city table have capitalized first letters.

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT public.country_by_city('Abha');`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call this parameter using simple quotes, for example:

```sql
SELECT public.country_by_city('Abha');
```

Comment: Jesus Christ, what a stupid mistake, thank you, it worked. But if I will write for example: 

`SELECT public.country_by_city(:city);`  it will return the same error, what should I change in that case?

Comment: This parameter required simple quotes, just that, this way `:city` maybe is something related to your driver and variable binding